# Possible to customize TinyMCE Quick Insert toolbar as icon button that expands when clicked?

Tags: tinymce

I'm currently setting up a TinyMCE 6 editor and trying to tweak the appearance/behavior of the Quick Insert toolbar (a.k.a. quickbar).

Its default behavior within the editor is that, upon hitting enter and starting a new line or clicking onto an empty line, an inline menu with options (e.g. insert image, insert link, etc.) will appear.

Ideally, I'd like an icon button to appear instead, and only expand that options menu when clicked, but there's nothing in [the quickbar docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/quickbars/) that suggests this is a possibility.

Curious if anyone has achieved this in TinyMCE, either through Quick Insert toolbar customization or otherwise (context menus, custom components/plugins, etc.).

I've attempted some hacky solutions but so far haven't made any progress. Hoping there's an elegant solution before I fully commit to grafting something on top of the TinyMCE code. Thanks!